# Install interrupt when trying to install mongoldb

Tags: raspbian-stretch, mongodb

when installing mongodb on my Pi 3 B I had a power outage and when I turned it back on and I try to re install it again the following is what is displayed

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
mongodb is already the newest version (1:2.4.14-4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 271 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf (1.58.0+dfsg-5.1+rpi1+b1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf (--configure):
too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/info/libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf.triggers'
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-clients:
mongodb-clients depends on libboost-filesystem1.58.0; however:
Package libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-clients (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb-server:
mongodb-server depends on mongodb-clients; however:
Package mongodb-clients is not configured yet.
mongodb-server depends on libboost-filesystem1.58.0; however:
Package libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb:
mongodb depends on mongodb-server (>= 1:2.4.1-2); however:
Package mongodb-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf
mongodb-clients
mongodb-server
mongodb
```

Answer (score 3):

I would first try to remove the offending package with

```
sudo apt-get purge libboost-filesystem
```

or perhaps try to remove the damaged file with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/libboost-filesystem1.58.0:armhf.triggers
```

then try to install `mongodb` again.

If that doesn't help, I'd simply reflash the OS and restart from scratch, unless I had a very good reason not to.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately neither of these commands worked, flashing the OS is a last resort as i have spent alot if time configuring the GPIOS to be set up to allow the connection of a fingerprint sensor so i am trying to get a fix.

Comment: @CaolanMcBride why does both commands not work? What are the error messages?

Comment: @CaolanMcBride Do you have a backup of that GPIO configuration? Can you make it now? Actually you should do a backup regardless of the problem at hand. It's up to you of course, but broken `dpkg` setup may take a lot of time to fix, and I would rather invest that time in doing things properly if I were you.

Comment: Thanks for the help @DmitryGrigoryev, from another source i was told that whilst the Pi 3 B has a 64 bit processor and mongodb is 64 bit the raspbian stretch os is 32 bit meaning it probably would not have worked anyway. Can i ask you another question? Would I still be able to connect to an AWS EC2 instance with pymongo without having mongo installed locally on the machine?

Comment: @CaolanMcBride I have no experience with AWS, but I think you could ask a separate question about it. Just make sure you search the site first. Good luck!